# How to balance coin system for Idle Runner?

Tags: game-design, level-design, balance

I have a classic mobile runner with left/right swipe controls, where each level player can collect different amounts of coins. (For example on level 1 coin amount is 100, on level 5 amount is 70 and also it depends on how a player will play (collect all coins or no)).
And at the end of the level, I have a mini-game, where the player can multiply the collected amount by, 1,2,3,4,5 and I have an upgrade system, at the start of the game, where the player should spend his coins to upgrade finish mini-game coin multiplication amount (for example if without upgrade maximum multiply amount is 20, when he upgraded to 5th level, they multiply amount will be 25).

So the question is, how to balance Upgrade Price for final mini game, and final mini game multiplication numbers, to have a balanced coin system for the game.

Comment: Your first challenge will be to define what "balanced" means for your game. There's no one standard definition or formula that applies to all games. A good way to start attacking this is to ask "what outcomes would be bad / what do I want to avoid?" eg, you might want to ensure that your average player never hits a situation where they can't afford even a single upgrade after a level out of the first 5. That helps you narrow down "what outcomes are good / what do I want to tune to achieve?" - edit your question to include this detail and we can offer strategies for how to achieve that.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for answer, yep my balanced outcome is for player having enough coins after each level to upgrade only one time

Comment: That's going to be at odds with the design details you've shown so far. You have a 30% variance between levels, a 100% variance in how many coins players collect, and a 500% variance in how well they perform at the multiplier minigame. So if you tune things for a medium-low scoring player to unlock one upgrade at a time, a high-scoring player will likely be pulling in upgrades five or more at a time. Are any of these mechanics flexible, to try to get less variance in the baseline scoring system? ([See this GDC talk](https://gdcvault.com/play/1025195/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Managing))

Comment: I don't understand how the minigame multipliers of 1 to 5 interact with the upgrades which add another multiplier of 20 to 25. Can you clarify?